# Is Weblogic Node Manager SSL setup required while implementiing SSL for Application

Tags: ssl, weblogic12c

In Weblogic, I have more than one `Machines` created using `Node Manager`. We have been told to setup `SSL` implementation for our Application which is deployed across created machines in a single `Weblogic Admin Console`.

So for the Application we had configured certificate using `.jks` file and configured SSL listen port by enabling it.

However we have been told to secure Node Manager machines in which application are deployed across as well. While enabling Node Manager type to `SSL` instead of `Plain` I am getting `SSLException`. By the fact we no need to secure Machines which were created using Node Manager, only securing Application is sufficient. Is am I right. Else is it required to Secure `Machines -> Node Manager` as well.

When I am turning `SSL` in `Machines -> Node Manager`, what are the things I have to consider to avoid SSLException. Is the Weblogic restart required If configure this or so. For now I do not have UNIX access, hence I couldn't do that at this moment.

Please advise on this situation. Without securing `Machines -> Node Manager` I am able run the application. But not able to access it using https. Only http for the Application is working.

Please advise on the situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSL for node manager is optional as there's no application related sensitive data that flows in this layer.

You mention even after configuring jks you can't get the server and hence the application listening on https. Could you elaborate what steps did you follow. Note this has nothing to do with node manager

Comment: Thanks for Confirming that securing `Node Manager `is not mandated if we need to secure `Application` which we deployed. We ran `WLST script` created by our team to secure the `App`. We're able to make it up & running. However `https` port is unreachable,- Mostly certificate - `.jks` related issue, let me through with it and confirm over here. Thanks.